# Xcode 7.3: Your account already has a valid iOS Development certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, certificate, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm unable Archive app for Ad Hoc Distribution on Xcode 7.3.

[image]

When Archive my project for Ad Hoc Distribution on Xcode 7.3, I receive this alert. I've tried many things but no luck.
On pressing **Reset button**, Xcode revokes the old Certificate and create the new one with the same name, but still showing this Alert again and again.

Comment: You need to install the public and private keys associated with the development profile onto the Mac you are using. They can be found in the Key-chain application, and simply transferred over.

Comment: Try this one might be help you
refreshing the account under Xcode > preferences > accounts > [accountname]

Comment: @Hitesh Surani I already did this many times but find no success.